# PHP ORM library based on the Data Mapper pattern

Tags: php, orm, datamapper

For a PHP application with a complex domain model, I don't want to use the Active Record pattern, I need instead the Data Mapper pattern (as presented in Zend Framework).

Do you know any library that could help me for the ORM part, or else a link to a documentation on "how to do it right" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching, i found 2 Data Mapper ORM :

- Xyster : really great, but developped by a couple of people, so I can't use it professionally (even though it seems really great)
- Doctrine version 2 : will be integrated to Zend Framework 2, will support the Data Mapper pattern, and seems to be the best option ever with possibilities inspired by J2EE and Hibernate. Unfortunately, still in beta.

Note : Doctrine 1.0 is not based on the Data Mapper pattern but on Active Record, as Propel. These are not fullfilling my needs.

In conclusion, **the answer, for now, is : there is none.**

Comment: Why won't you use Xyster professionally? The license is pretty flexible.

Comment: Because this is developped by 2 people only